# html css image always on top

Tags: html, css, image

I have a problem with my website. I want a picture to be in the background and text in the foreground. My code is:

```
    <body>
<a id="Head">Gute <a id="Head2">Server</a></a>
<div id="bg">
  <img src="bg.jpg" alt="">
</div>
```

**and CSS:**

```
#Head   {
        font-size: 500px;
        color: #00DFFC;
}
#Head2  {
        font-size: 500px;
}

#bg {
  position: fixed; 
  top: -50%; 
  left: -50%; 
  width: 200%; 
  height: 200%;
}
#bg img {
  position: absolute; 
  top: 0; 
  left: 0; 
  right: 0; 
  bottom: 0; 
  margin: auto; 
  min-width: 50%;
  min-height: 50%;
}
```

When I use this code the background is in the foreground and the text is invisible.

Comment: You shouldn't put an anchor tag within an anchor tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `z-index`es

```
#Head {position: relative; z-index: 2;}
#bg {z-index: 1}
```

Than, `<a>` in another `<a>` isn't valid HTML, use only one link (eg. with `span`), or `<a href="">gute</a> <a href="">server</a>`.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the line

```
   <img src="bg.jpg" alt="">
```

Instead add in your style class

```
 body{
     background : url('bg.jpg');
  }
```